# Apache 2.2/PHP is not loading the correct php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I have been struggling with this for days. I have a windows server 2008 where I have installed Apache 2.2, PHP and MySql. I kept getting the error that mysql_connect was an unknown function, so I followed all guides I could find but with no result. I have now noticed that phpinfo says that php.ini dir is C:\Windows. This is strange since I've written this in httpd.conf:

```
PHPIniDir 'c:\PHP\'
LoadModule php5_module "c:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

How do I get apache and php to read my php.ini and thereby include mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your back slashes to forward:  `PHPIniDir c:/PHP/`

Comment: I have tried: PHPIniDir c:/PHP/, PHPIniDir 'c:/PHP/', PHPIniDir "c:/PHP/". All three variations makes it impossible to start Apache (The Requested operation has failed)

Comment: How about CLI afterward?

Comment: If I start httpd.exe from command line, it says 
The application has failed to start because MSVCR71.dll was not found, re-installing the application might solve the problem"

Comment: ...so I downloaded that dll and installed it and did some tweaking and actually everything works now. I am using this: `PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"` The solution was to start Apache from Command Line instead of taskbar. Otherwise I would never have found that error. Thanks :)